# UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString does not work second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Within UITableViewController I have a UIWebView with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString that is properly loaded the first time. Then the View Controller is dimissed upon user's 'Close', then it could be requested again.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  textComments.delegate=self;
NSString *path =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]
               stringByAppendingString:@"/demo.html"];
[textComments loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_textComments{
  NSString * html_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('editor1').innerHTML='%@';"
                            , self.commentHTML];
  [_textComments stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:html_string];
  [_textComments stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('editor1').focus();"];
}
```

demo.html is an HTML file with a textarea:

```
<textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="8">Content goes
here. ERROR: innerHTML not replaced!</textarea>
```

The idea is to replace the **<textarea>** value with the content of the variable **self.commentHTML**.

The first time the Table View Controller loads, it works fine replacing the value of **<textarea>** with **self.commentHTML** variable.

Upon user CLOSE action, another **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** happens to get the innerHTML value and it works fine as well, then I make sure that I dismiss the UIWebView outlet:

```
[textComments stopLoading];
[textComments removeFromSuperview];
textComments.delegate=nil;
self.textComments=nil;
```

So far, so good.
The problem is when the User launches the View Controller again, **UIWebView** loads with the pre-loaded **demo.html** content, but the JavaScript **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** on webViewDidFinishLoad is not happening. I already made sure that **webViewDidFinishLoad** is being fired. I also made sure that **didFailLoadWithError** is not being fired also.

Any ideas of why the second time that the View Controller is fired, the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is NOT happening?

I'm wondering if I have to destroy/dealloc/discharge something else that I'm not envisioning here upon CLOSE.

Thanks so much for any help.

**Edit to Include the full demo.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>CKEditor</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body><p><textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="8">Content goes here. ERROR: innerHTML not replaced!</textarea></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation: (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001214-BCIIEAFH) or other possibilities (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/ObjC_classic/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough code here to be sure, but my first guess would be that this sequence creates two separate elements of your dom with `<textarea id="editor1">` and that the javascript does execute, but places the content into the wrong textarea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited the question to add the demo.html code.

Comment: I only have one DOM textarea element on the demo.html file as you can see. I wonder if there some other way to destroy the View Controller Instance. Or to Destroy Javascript calls in case iOS thinks UIWebView  and its JS are still active.